# hiphop PHP download?

Tags: php, c++, hiphop

Where can you download the HipHop Code? I would really like to test it.

Interestingly enough if you go here:
http://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wikis

It must not exist or private because it redirects to github.com index.php page

So you can not even see the wiki or anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> git clone git://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php.git

Answer (score 3):

Chances are they released the article without notifying whomever is in charge of their GitHub account to open up the HipHop package. Go to http://github.com/facebook/ and simply keep tabs. Once it's public it'll show up there. If you click the 'Follow' link on the upper right, you'll get an email when its released.